# Git repo's branches are unavailable after being forked

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-fork

I have a pretty standard github repo with two branches, `master` and `some_branch`.

A friend of mine wanted to look at some of the stuff I did and maybe change it so he forked it as per [the instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo). When he's online on github he can see both branches of the repo, but when he tries to switch to the branch using terminal it tells him there is no such branch.

We both want to work on my branch.  How can we?

Comment: "The other instructions" say nothing about adding a remote; and furthermore this is done automatically when you git-clone the repo, as described in "the instructions". When you git-clone a repo, the cloned repo is set up so that the "origin" remote tracks the cloned repo. You should be all set. Your friend, who cloned your repo, can simply "git checkout some_branch", and git should automatically open a local branch that's tracking origin/some_branch.

Comment: Oops, used the wrong links. Thanks @Sam.  And that's what we thought, but it doesn't track origin/some_branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Forking** implies that the repository will diverge its state with respect to the origin repository.

What you might be looking for is to **clone** the repository.

After you clone, ensure your remote references are updated by running `git fetch`.

Then if you still can't `checkout` or `pull` a specific branch, I would check your permission settings for members of the GitHub repository.

Comment: So by forking it he loses access to the branches? But when viewing the repository online (at github.com) his fork still has both branches

Comment: Forking on GitHub will create a separate copy of your original repository for him to commit work to. Him committing to his copy of the repository (his fork) will not affect the original repository you are probably working in. He would have to perform a pull request to get you to accept a specific branch merge he thinks you should perform. If he just cloned your original repository instead of forking, you would both be referencing the same remote repository branches when doing fetch/pull/push.

Comment: We haven't even gotten to him commiting to the repository - I created a branch, he forked my repository, the branch shows up online on his forked repo, it does not show up on his desktop when using `git branch`.

Comment: If the branch you created is showing up in his forked repository in GitHub, I think he should just be able to `git fetch` and see it.